# Erro ao tentar buscar a ID do SQLite através do Spinner

Tags: android, android-adapter

Objeto Livro

```
public class Livros {
private int id;
private String nome;

public Livros() {}

public Livros (int id, String nome) {
    this.id = id;
    this.nome = nome;
}
public int getId () {
    return id;
}
public int setId (int id) {
    return id;
}
public int getNome () {
    return nome;
}
public int setNome (String nome) {
    return nome;
}
```

Classe do openHelper

```
public List<Livros> buscarLivros() {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getReadableDatabase();

    List<Livros> listLivros = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(ConsultasSQL.getRegistrosTabLivros(), null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Livros livros = new Livros();
            livros.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            livros.setNome(cursor.getString(1));

            listLivros.add(livro);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }
    sqLiteDatabase.close();
    return listLivros;
}
```

Main

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dataBase baseDeDados = new dataBase(this);
    SQLiteDatabase connection = baseDeDados.getWritableDatabase();

    Spinner spnLivros = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerLivros);

    ArrayList<Livros> arrayLivros = (ArrayList<Livros>) baseDeDados.buscarLivros();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adpLivros = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adpLivros .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spnLivros.setAdapter(adpLivros);

    for (Livros livros : arrayLivros) {
        adpLivros.add(livros.toString());
    }
}
```

Método select do Spinner

```
public onItemSelected (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int p, long id) {
    Livros livros = (Livros) parent.getSelectedItem();
    String buscaIdNome = "ID:" + livros.getId() + "Nome:" + livros.getNome();
    Log.i("TESTE:", buscaIdNome);
}
```

Erro:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.example.Livro
```

Antes de postar essa minha dúvida verifiquei inúmeros sites, inclusive este, mas nenhum deles achei a solução para este meu problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu *Adapter* gere objectos do tipo *String*, ele é declarado como `ArrayAdapter<String>`.

Por isso, quando faz

```
Livros livros = (Livros) parent.getSelectedItem();
```

está a tentar converter um objecto do tipo *String* em *Livros*, daí o erro:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.example.Livros

Para que o método `parent.getSelectedItem()` retorne *Livros*, o *Adapter* deve ser declarado como `ArrayAdapter<Livros>` e o *array* que ele gere ser do tipo `ArrayList<Livros>`.
Esse *array* deve ser passado ao construtor ao criar o *ArrayAdapter*.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ....
    ....    
    ArrayList<Livros> arrayLivros = (ArrayList<Livros>) baseDeDados.buscarLivros();

    ArrayAdapter<Livros> adpLivros = 
        new ArrayAdapter<Livros>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayLivros);

    adpLivros.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spnLivros.setAdapter(adpLivros);

    //Não é necessário, foi passado o array com os livros ao Adapter
    //for (Livros livros : arrayLivros) {
    //    adpLivros.add(livros.toString());
    //}
}
```

O *ArrayAdapter* usa o método `toString()`, da classe a que se refere o *Array*, para obter o valor de cada item do *Spinner*.
Por isso, a classe *Livros* tem de sobrescrever esse método de forma retornar esse valor.

Adicione à classe Livros:

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return nome;
}
```

Agora que o *Adaptar* gere objectos do tipo *Livros*, já é possível fazer o *cast* do objecto retornado por `parent.getSelectedItem()` para *Livros*.

<sub>**Nota:** A classe Livros deveria chamar-se Livro, já que é um livro que ela representa e não um conjunto/lista deles.</sub>

Comment: ramaral, após fazer as alterações que foram levantadas, agora ele funciona com cast. No entanto, após eu retirar o laço, o meu spinner não apresentou mais nenhuma informação. Como se os dados não fossem mais carregados.

Comment: Você está a passar o array `arrayLivros` ao construtor do `ArrayAdapter<Livros>` desta forma: `new ArrayAdapter<Livros>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayLivros);` ?

Comment: ramaral, acabei esquecendo de passar o arrayLivros ao final. Muito obrigado!